# Why is this only returning whole numbers when i used double throughout?

Tags: c++

Just wondering why this area calculation code only returns whole numbers, even though I used double throughout.

```
#include <iostream>

#define pi 3.14

piCalc(double radi) {
  double result;
  result = (radi * radi) * pi;
  return result;
}

int main() {
  double radius;
  std::cout << "Welcome to the circle area calculator. Please enter your radius"
            << std::endl;
  std::cin >> radius;
  std::cout << "your answer is " << piCalc(radius) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "thankyou for using the area calculator" << std::endl;
}
```

Even when i enter a float, for example 5.3, i still only return 88, when it should be 88.25. Thanks.

Comment: Where is return type of `piCalc`?

Comment: In C++20, you have [`std::numbers::pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
piCalc(double radi){
```

You are missing the return type. This isn't valid C++. In (ancient?) C you could omit the return type and `int` was assumed. Some compilers still allow this as non-standard extension. Make the return type `double`:

```
double piCalc(double radi){
```

In general you need to take care with compiler extensions. For example gcc is rather lax with its default settings and compiles lots of code that shouldn't according to standard C++. `-pedantic` option can help to spot such undesired use of compiler specific extensions.

Comment: non-ancient gcc versions don't let you do this unless you specifically use `-fpermissive` https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MfK3sW